# Fast Interleaving of Data

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I'm working with some piece of hardware (the hardware itself is not important) and I need to split some block data intro separate pieces in order to make the thing run faster.

So I have, for example  a contiguous block of memory X words long. For visualization, I'm arranging it into 50 word lines below:

```
001  002  003  004  005 006 007 ...
051  052  053  054  055 056 057 ...
101  102  103  104  105 106 107 ...
151  152  153  154  155 156 157 ...
```

I need a fast way of splitting these into four separate blocks:

Block1

```
001  003  005 007 ...
101  103  105 107 ...
```

Block2

```
002  004  006 ...
102  104  106 ...
```

Block3

```
051  053  055 057 ...
151  153  155 157 ...
```

Block4

```
052  054  056 ...
152  154  156 ...
```

Or, basically:

```
Block1   Block2   Block1   Block2 ...
Block3   Block4   Block3   Block4 ...
Block1   Block2   Block1   Block2 ...
Block3   Block4   Block3   Block4 ...
```

Now doing this is as simple as using for-loops. But what is a more optimized/parallel way of doing this? (No MPI stuff, this happens on an app running on the desktop).

So summing it up, just to be clear:

1. I have data as shown above.
2. I'm sending this data several devices (outside the PC). This data needs to be sent down the wire as 4 separate blocks (to the separate devices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prime example where SSE can help you. It's very good at data shuffling as well as streaming data from memory and back. On some non-x86 architectures, there are similar ISA extensions available (e.g. AltiVec)

Comment: got resources/links/book to start on?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It sounds like you're passing the data to an external interface.  If this is anything as slow as a gigabit ethernet interface, then the bottleneck will be at the wire and not how quickly you can compose data.  Just iterate over the data to build your blocks in any manner that seems convenient for your code.

---

Perhaps what you want to do is pass the blocks around using an offset/stride notation.  Essentially, each block is described from its starting address, the into the block where the first element appears, the number of bytes between elements, and the number of bytes between rows.  So, something like:

```
       Block
         1    2    3    4
base     0    0    50   50
first    0    1    0    1
offset   2    2    2    2
stride   100  100  100  100
```

So you could work on the data in parallel (assuming you don't have to worry about writes) something like this

```
struct Block {
    int base;
    int first;
    int offset;
    int stride;
    int cols; rows;
};

/* given some reasonable block[n] and buffer */

for ( int row = 0; col < block[n].rows; ++row)
    for (int col = 0; row < block[n].cols; ++col)
    {
        int cell = buffer[
                      block[n].base + 
                      block[n].first +
                      row*block[n].stride + 
                      col*block[n].offset]
        doSomething(cell);
    }
```

Comment: thanks! this is fine for manipulating the blocks inside the app. but not good when it is passed to the hardware.  the hardware, being having litle resources, needs the contiguous data for each block.

Comment: No, it isn't very slow, but there are interconnects that are fast enough that the processor can have a hard time keeping them fed.  They are all much faster than gigabit ethernet.  PCI-Express, Myranet, some varieties of FibreChannel are all examples of this.

Comment: in this case, the ethernet is far from being the bottleneck. thanks.